# Use Dropbox Sync Api with PHP

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm currently planning a project which should share files across many plattforms. For this need the Dropbox Sync Api sounds pretty amazing BUT in addition to Android, iOS and C# I also need to access my files from a php web app. Is there any third party Api for PHP or can I use Dropbox Sync for Android, iOS and Windows and access this data using the Core Api on my website? Or will I have to use the Core Api on all my services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the Core API in your web app. In fact, it would be strange to use the Sync API there, since the Sync API was designed for client applications that need to cache data and work offline.

The Sync API is really just an SDK built on top of the same Core API, so there's no reason you can't mix the use of both on different platforms.

BTW, since you mentioned it, Dropbox doesn't have any official SDK for C#, but there are a number of third-party ones.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought the data would be somehow "encrypted" when using the Sync Api.

And yes I know that there are no official SDKs for .NET